# I have an Android app to communicate with pic micro controller using uart pin. But i cant install the app on device. Any solution?

Tags: android, android-kernel, odroid

Am using odroid C2 with Android 5.1, And using Github code (https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback/tree/master/app). I can see COM Port in Device manager when i connect the RX TX pin with PC using a bridge.
And I can't install the app on my device, it fails.
Error:

> Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.windows10.uart_three-1                                           com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.example.windows10.uart_app requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.things; failing!
>
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Comment: The exception is pretty straight forward. You need to include the library `com.google.android.things` in your application

Comment: its already included.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
You need either to remove com.google.android.things from your manifest or add Google Apps to your device. Because by default Odroid-C2 does not have it.

All packages that start with com.google are Google's proprietary software. Which means its closed source(same as your code I suppose).

When you add the requirement of some library that starts with 'com.google', you require that package will be in your device. Which in Odroid's case they are not there, at least not all of them.

Now why Odroid does not have these packages? Well because it:
1.Costs alot of money
2.Depends on Google's strategic interests to disallow such thing. Which means Google can control which manufacturers produce devices, thats right! They are the .

So unless you want to be an outlaw and install Google's apps, you should reconsider using their products, well technically that requires you to stop being their product.

Comment: according to your answer app should work on an android phone. But it gives the same result when i try to install on an android phone.

Comment: can u suggest any package or sample code for UART RX TX pin communication??

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "UART RX TX pin communication".